# Should a collaborator who recently passed away be included as an author?

Tags: publications, etiquette, authorship

I am finishing a publication based on my PhD thesis. The writing process took a long time, and a while ago, one of the collaborators passed away. The paper is mostly about the development of a model, but does include some experimental data. The data  have been published before, though I did some additional analyses.

The deceased collaborator was involved in discussions about possible mechanisms that I incorporated into the model, but not in the actual modeling process. The data was collected in his lab. He never saw the manuscript in any state, though he did see my thesis, which has substantial overlap with the paper. Should he be included as an author, or not?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Posthumous Publication](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/776/7734)