# How to raise concerns about plagiarism when the corresponding author has passed away?

Tags: authorship, plagiarism

After I left graduate school, my advisor (the corresponding author) and another person (the first author) published a paper with a lot of data from my master's thesis. I was not even acknowledged, and I feel this may constitute plagiarism. Normally I would reach out to my former advisor, but unfortunately, they have passed away.

So: how should I proceed? Who would deal with issues and questions pertaining to authorship and plagiarism in this circumstance?

Comment: Is there a reason not to contact the other author?

Comment: I moved some information from the comments into the main post. The issue here seems to be plagiarism / authorship dispute, not a conflict of interest, so I have updated that reference as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deceased author and conflict of interest statement](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151216/deceased-author-and-conflict-of-interest-statement)

Comment: I don't understand the duplicate votes. The linked question is about who can sign a conflict of interest form on behalf of a deceased author. OP's situation is nothing like this.

Answer (score 4):

If there is fault here, it is probably due to the former mentor. You can contact the editor of the journal in which it was published and/or the remaining author.

In fact, it is probably a good idea to contact both, raising your concerns. But you don't have the option of contacting the corresponding author as is obvious.